# Serving files from SQL Server via REST api (any content-type (data-type))

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api2

I've built a feature to allow users to upload files from a mobile app. I have a RESTful .NET C# Web API endpoint which stores the files BYTE_ARRAY in a SQL Server table. No problem.

Now, when the user wants to view the file, my question is, what options to I have to send them the file?

The user will be on some page which shows some content. If they click `this link`, I will call some endpoint and I will get the record they are interested in from the table with the files. Now, keep in mind that they can upload any type of file (Word, PDF, Excel, etc.).  When I initially store the BYTE_ARRAY I also capture its content type so it can be reconstructed.

Now, my question is

1. Do I reconstruct the file on the server (if so how) into its type (a PNG will reconstruct to a PNG based on its content type; a Word doc, into a Word doc based on its content-type, etc.). Then, I persist the file in some temp storage location. Then I send back to the app (UX) the new `URL` for the asset.  Then the app (UX) will call back to that endpoint and get the file and do whatever it wants (i.e., `https://my-website.com/somePath/fileName.fileExtension`)
2. Do I respond to the app (UX) with the `Stream` somehow and also provide the content type, which accomplishes the above - in that a file is being sent over HTTP which the app (UX) can do something with?

Answer (score 0):

I went with Google's Firebase!  Problem solved!